# Is it possible to read Dynamic Named Ranges in Excel using OpenXML?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

Using OpenXML, you can get a list of the named ranges in an Excel document using something similar to:

```
 IEnumerable<DefinedName> names = document
          .WorkbookPart
          .Workbook
          .DefinedNames
          .Cast<DefinedName>();
```

Each of these `DefinedName`'s has a `Text` property, which defines the range that it refers to, e.g.

```
Sheet1!$B$3:$D$8
```

which we can then parse, and use to retrieve the data. At least that's how I understand the process so far.

However, with a dynamic range, the text property can contain something like:

```
OFFSET(Sheet1!$F$3,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$F:$F),1)
```

This is not a range, it is a formula which returns a range, and it is the result of this formula that I need.

Is it possible to calculate this formula, or is the result already stored somewhere in the spreadsheet that I can read? Or is there some other way in which I can read a dynamic named range?

This question is specifically about OpenXML. I know that it can be done using other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel Defined Names are really named formulas rather than named ranges. So you would need a method such as VBA Evaluate to coerce the formula to a range or a result.

AFAIK OpenXML does not have such a method, so you would have to write your own formula parser and evaluator, or use some other tool.

Comment: Thanks. I'd pretty much been coming to that conclusion myself, but nice to have it confirmed.